# Center square SVG in either Landscape or Portrait orientation?

Tags: html, svg, screen-orientation, mobile-website

I have a simple square SVG art element on a mobile web site.  How do I horizontally center this on portrait mode AND then vertical center [onOrientationChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange)?  Basically perfect center fit regardless of orientation and Safari- & Chrome-friendly??

There are diatribes on vertical centering.  Is there a simple and effective way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is hard to help you debug imaginary code. Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration your browser requirements (I suppose you meant latest ones) your best option for centering both horizontally and vertically at the same time is **flexbox**. Also, this way you don't need to check orientation as the SVG will stay centered.

There's a handy guide on css-tricks about the different properties of flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here's some code to demonstrate a possible solution using flexbox:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* remove margin added by "user agent stylesheet" */

  /* Make sure the body takes up the whole screen */
  /* (unless we cannot center vertically) */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* Center SVG with flexbox. */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" widht="100px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="red" />
  <path d="M 200 100 L 300 300 L 100 300 z" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Works like a champ, and simplifies greatly.  Thanks.  Note I had to add the `width:100vw;height:100vh;` to the `<svg>` tag, as it doesn't seen to inherit height from the body (Chrome58).